# Custom font won't load, copied CSS file from fontmaker too, no result

Tags: html, css, fonts, loading, truetype

I have been trying to import a custom font into my HTML. I have downloaded the font pack from FontSquirrel.

When I check my fonts on my page with the developer tools, it says 3 fonts have been imported, the TTF, the WOFF, and WOFF2, but when I click on them, they only show regular font style.

This is my CSS, I have added the src URL (but without the src link, it is also not working). I have downloaded the kit, unpacked it into my about-me map, and deleted the zip file.

```
@font-face   {

font-family: 'moon_flower_boldregular';
src: url('C:\Users\M de Witte\Desktop\html\aboutme\webfontkit')
src: url('moon_flower_bold-webfont.eot');
src: url('moon_flower_bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('moon_flower_bold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
     url('moon_flower_bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('moon_flower_bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('moon_flower_bold-webfont.svg#moon_flower_boldregular') 

format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}


p  {

  font-family: moon_flower_boldregular;
  font-size: 30px;

}
```

I hope somebody can say what I am doing wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: can you tell me the location of the `moon_flower_bold-webfont.eot` file?

Comment: Mabye url('moon_flower...') should look like url('../fonts/moon_flower...')? If you have separate folder for fonts.
Try to take font name into quotation marks.

Comment: @Patel, it is in the same map, so many options and comments, I am going to try them all and see what the result is.

Answer (score 0):

Check you url source the slash are opposites

your code:

`src: url('C:\Users\M de Witte\Desktop\html\aboutme\webfontkit')`

must be:

`src: url('C:/Users/M de Witte/Desktop/html/aboutme/webfontkit')`

and also avoid some spaces in sources `/M de Witte/` remove the space

I think that's solve your problem.

Comment: Local paths should be avoided. Use RELATIVE paths

Comment: yes, he must practice to always use relative paths, I just copy his paths

Comment: Sorry for not using the right paths. So much to learn and so much stuff going on, I am a beginner :( . And the slashes are not working ( I copied the path straight away from my maps, and with other images on my page, I have the spaces and the slashes, and they work fine )

Comment: Add source in every fonts you have

Comment: For some reason, the font's could not be found in my webfontkit-map, but as soon as I placed them in my aboutme map, it worked. Thank godddd finally and thank  you guys.

Answer (score 0):

Use relative path. E.g. if your css file is in `css` folder and fonts are in `fonts` folder, path is this:
`url('../fonts/moon_flower_bold-webfont.eot')`.
Note that you must define this path for ALL font files, not only for first. And be careful about semicolons:

```
@font-face   {

    font-family: 'moon_flower_boldregular';
    src: url('../fonts/moon_flower_bold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/moon_flower_bold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/moon_flower_bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/moon_flower_bold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/moon_flower_bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/moon_flower_bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/moon_flower_bold-webfont.svg#moon_flower_boldregular') format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, my path was not correctly linked.

I checked developer tools again at f12, and checked my fonts, and saw suddenly 3 errors, where it showed the fonts could not be found. I placed them into my previous submap (aboutme), and it worked.

Thanks for the replies people, this site is awesome.